# Error in importing an exisiting repository in Github

Tags: github, import, fork

I am trying to import a repo into another repo in GITHUB. I followed the following steps.

1. Copy the HTTPS url of the clone repo
2. Went to the new repo and clicked on import repository, enetered onld repositorys clone url

After that I see the error `No source repositories were detected at https://github.com/xxxx/yyyy.git. Please check the URL and try again`.

Whats the possible error here. Also what's the difference between importing the repo vs forking the old one

Answer (score 1):

What I get from question is that there is a git repo A and you want the contents of git repo A to another git repo B. If this it this is how you do it.

1. Clone git repo B in a folder locally. `git clone <your ssh link for git repo B>`
2. Copy the SSH link of git repo A.
3. Go to git repo B through your terminal and create a new-origin. `git remote add  new-origin <paste the link you copied>`
4. Now pull from the new-origin you just added. `git pull new-origin main`.

Here `new-origin` can be replaced by any name you want to give to the new remote repository. Your original remote repository that is `origin` will remain.

[You can also read this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/)

Comment: Can it work using the hhtp link instead of ssh ?